# Why liquid helium boils as its temperature is lowered?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, low-temperature-physics

Water boils when heated. [Liquid helium boils](https://youtu.be/2Z6UJbwxBZI) when cooled. Not only that. It boils initially and then stops. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, cooling does not cause liquid helium to boil. Just the opposite: Heat causes it to boil. The boiling point of liquid helium at standard pressure is around 4.22K. If you pour liquid helium into a container that is "hotter" than that temperature, the helium will absorb heat from the container, causing the helium to boil, and causing the container to cool down.  The boiling will stop if and when the temperature of the container gets down to 4.22K.

This is exactly the same as what happens if you pour liquid water into a hot container where, in this case, "hot" means hotter than 100C (373K). The water will absorb heat from the container, causing the water to boil, and causing the temperature of the container to drop. The boiling will stop if and when the temperature of the container comes down to 100C.

The video that you cited appears to be a clip from a longer video, and I can't tell from context what came before, but in the first half minute or so, it seems to show that when the container gets cold enough, the boiling stops. The rest of the video talks about a whole different phenomenon—[*superfluidity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluidity)—which occurs in helium at a substantially lower temperature than the boiling point.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the video, it is possible to demonstrate a similar boiling effect with water.  If you take a small container of room temperature water (e.g., 25 deg C), place it in a vacuum bell jar, and pull a strong vacuum on it, you will find that at a low enough pressure, the water starts boiling with no apparent heat source causing that boiling.  Water has a vapor pressure that is dependent only on its temperature, and when the ambient pressure inside the bell jar reaches the vapor pressure of the water, the water will boil.  The heat for that boiling comes from the water itself, and as a consequence, the temperature of the water drops as boiling proceeds.  This means that you can take the temperature of the water before pulling a vacuum on it (e.g., 23 deg C) and take the temperature of the water again immediately after the experiment (e.g., 14 deg C), and find that the temperature of the water actually dropped, even though the water was boiling.  For a demonstration of this effect, see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glLPMXq6yc0).